# image onload not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 2 images but the onload does not fire for the second image. But in chrome resources the image is there all nice and loaded... what could cause this ?

This is my code:

```
var test = new Array();
    test[0] = new Image();
    test[0].src = 'tile1.png';  
    test[1]  = new Image();
    test[1].src = 'tile2.png';      


    test[0].onload = function(){    
        console.log('loaded 1');    

            test[1].onload = function(){
               console.log('loaded 2');
        }
    }
```

I only get `loaded 1` in my `console.log` but never `loaded 2`.

Yet in Chrome network it shows `tile2.png` so why would my `onload` function not fire??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `onload` function is declared within the first, so remove it and place it outside.

```
var test = new Array();
test[0] = new Image();
test[0].src = 'tile1.png';  
test[1]  = new Image();
test[1].src = 'tile2.png';      


test[0].onload = function(){    
    console.log('loaded 1'); 
}

test[1].onload = function(){
    console.log('loaded 2');
}
```

Comment: May i ask the difference in behaviour between in the function and outside the function ?

Comment: @Dave The only difference is that the if the onload function is declared within the first onload function, then the second onload function never will be attached to the onload event until some point slightly after the first image has loaded. At that point in time, you are very likely to completely miss the onload event of the second image, in which case the onload event handler for the second image will do nothing.